# Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: Upgrade request required

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

Has any one seen this error `Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: Upgrade request required` in **Kubernetes**

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this before and there were a couple of issues to address:

1. The Nginx that was proxying requests did not contain the following
   config (required for HTTP2 support):

   ```
   proxy_set_header Upgrade 'websocket';
   proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
   ```
2. And we also had to switch our Classic Load Balancer on AWS (ELB)
   with an Application Load Balancer (ALB).

TBH, the question is a bit vague. Where are you seeing this exactly? It needs more context.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864580/error-forwarding-ports-upgrade-request-required-error-in-helm-of-a-kubernete

Answer (score 1):

we were able to resolve it by using ip for the kube server instead of the hostname. This is caused by load balancers not supporting HTTP/2. Instead of using the https://hostname URL to Kube, use the IP address, and disable SSL verification

```
kubectl config set-cluster $NAME --user=$USER --server=$KUBE_URL --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
```

Comment: Could you please explain this answer further? How did you get that $KUBE_URL?

Comment: I had mentioned that in my other answer:
> "And we also had to switch our Classic Load Balancer on AWS (ELB) with an Application Load Balancer (ALB)."
HTTP/2 websocket connections were failing on my ELB so I switched to an ALB and it worked (probably should've tried to change the security group to allow just TCP and not focus specifically on HTTP / HTTPS).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today when trying to use Garden.io for a cluster running in Jelastic.

Found the solution in [this Github comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1455#issuecomment-533802309):

First acquire a local binary for Tiller (server-version of Helm), either by [compiling](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#from-source-linux-macos) or by [downloading it from the release page](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v2.14.3).

Then run:

```sh
$ export HELM_HOST=":44134"
$ tiller -listen ${HELM_HOST} -alsologtostderr >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This will run a local version of the Kubernetes Helm Server. Now try your original command again, kubectl, that will delegate to this local Helm instead and manage to connect.